# php simpleXml generate a invalid XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have tryed some things to figure out what wrong with my code, but i dont see the problem.

Simply i have a structured assoziative Array like this:

```
    $data = array(
        'field1' => array(
            'filed11' => '',
            'field12' => array(
                'field121' => 'blub'
            )
        ), 
        'field2' => 'foo',
        'field3' => array(
            'field31' => 'val',
            'field32' => 'other value'
        )
    );
```

i have writen a small recursive method to generate an xml from the Array:

```
protected function buildXmlFromArray(SimpleXMLElement $xml, $data)
{
    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {                    
                $child = $xml->addChild($key);
                $this->buildXmlFromArray($child, $value);                    
            } else {
                $xml->addChild($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i generate the root-node and put it in the method:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root />');        
    $res = $this->buildXmlFromArray($xml, $data);

    print_r($xml->asXML());
    exit;
```

i would expect that iam getting somthing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <field1>
        <filed11 />
        <field12>
            <field121>blub</field121>
        </field12>
    </field1>
    <field2>foo</field2>
    <field3>
        <field31>val</field31>
        <field32>other value</field32>
    </field3>
</root>
```

but iam getting an invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <field1>
        <filed11>
            <field12>
                <field121>blub</field121>
            </field12>
        </field1>
        <field2>foo</field2>
        <field3>
            <field31>val</field31>
            <field32>other value</field32>
        </field3>
    </root>
```

so field11 is not closed 
Whats wrong with this?

My PHP Version is 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: Just tried and can't reproduce the output (I get `<filed11/>` as expected).

Comment: Same here, getting the expected output

Comment: *facepalm* currently iam working on a restservice, iam using the restlet client for testing ... the output was setted to "pretty", after setting it to raw i see the valid xml ... its time to do something else, thanks a lot